# Get the selected radio values into next page using php for online examiation

Tags: php, session

I am developing online quiz system. I want to display user selected Answers and right answers after complete the exam. Please help me.

Here is my code questions.php code

```
<?php 

require 'dataconnection.php';

$res = mysql_query("select * from questions where category_id=$category ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

echo $rows;
$i=1;
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

   if($i==1){?>
        <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>

           <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['Question'];?></p>
           <input type="radio" value="A" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option A'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="B" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option B'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="C" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option C'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="D" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option D'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name=''/>                                                                      
           <br/> 

           <input type="hidden" id="offset" value='<?php echo $i+1; ?>' />
           <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>


        </div>    

   <?php  }

   if($i<$rows){?>
       <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>

           <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['Question'];?></p>
           <input type="radio" value="A" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option A'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="B" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option B'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="C" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option C'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="D" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option D'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/>                                                                      
           <br/>
           <input type="hidden" id="offset" value='<?php echo $i+1; ?>' /> 
           <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button> 

           <input type="hidden" id="offset" value='<?php echo $i+1; ?>' />  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

           <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>


       </div>    

   <?php  }elseif($i==$rows){?>
       <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
           <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['Question'];?></p>
           <input type="radio" value="A" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option A'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="B" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option B'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="C" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option C'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" value="D" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo  $result['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $result['Option D'];?>
           <br/>
           <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/>                                                                      
           <br/>              

           <input type="hidden" id="offset" value='<?php echo $i+1; ?>' /> 
           <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>
           <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>
       </div>
   <?php } $i++;   $_SESSION['questions'][]=$result;
}
?>
```

I stored the all questions in session variable and display in next page. But i don't know how to get the selected radio button values.

Result.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['questions'];


for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) { ?>
    <div id='questions'  class='container-fluid cont'>

        <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i+1?>.<?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['Question'];?></p>
        <input type="radio" value="A" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['QNo'];?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['Option A'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="B" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['QNo'];;?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['Option B'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="C" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['QNo'];;?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['Option C'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="D" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>' name='<?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['QNo'];;?>'/><?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['Option D'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $_SESSION['questions'][$i]['QNo'];;?>' name='<?php echo $result['QNo'];?>'/>                                                                      
        <br/> 
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV3qA.jpg]